# Dry Hopping Measuring Cup

Tags: hops, sanitation, dry-hop

When measuring hops for dry hopping, do I need to sanitize the cup I put the hops in on my scale? I recently started buying hops in bulk and I've never had to weigh hops before pouring them into the fermenter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes keep it clean, but no you do not need to sanitize it, the properties of finished beer and the properties of the hops will keep most spoilage organisms at bay.

Comment: Cool, that's what I figured, but wanted to make sure. Not something I'd seen specifically addressed before.